# vim "Unexpected 'INDENT'" coffeescript on every new line

Tags: vim, coffeescript

I am quite new to vim and I am trying to edit coffeescript.

Whenever I take try and add a new line, the coffeescript no longer compiles, I always get the following error:

> Error: Parse error on line 14: Unexpected 'INDENT'

This happens every time I take a new line.

If I edit the same file in textmate and take a new line then all is good.

Anybody any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `:set list` to check whether the **INDENT** is `white-spaces` or `tabs`.

Type `/\t` to search for `tabs`.

Comment: it is white-spaces, do I need to turn it to tabs?

Comment: Maybe you mix white-spaces with tabs.

Comment: what's the result of `:set et?` (this command contains `?`) ?

Comment: yes, it appears to be a mixture of white-space and tabs.  I started the project in textmate which is inserting tabs and it mow appears vim is inserting white-space for tabs.

Comment: replacing all tabs with spaces works.  Thanks for the help.  Is there a quick way to replace all the tabs for spaces?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem...

I solved it in the following way, still I don't know the cause...

```
$ npm uninstall -g coffee-script
(unbuild coffee-script@1.6.3)
$ npm install -g coffee-script
(coffee-script@1.6.3)
```